# Find a biholomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\backslash [1,\infty)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a biholomorphic function (holomorphic with inverse holomorphic) $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\backslash [1,\infty)$ where $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

I know $g:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ where $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0\}$ and $g(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is a biholomorphic function, so I think I must compose it with another function to cover $\mathbb{C}\backslash [1,\infty)$, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Koebe function adjusted appropriately works $f(z)=-4K(z)=-\frac{4z}{(1-z)^2}$; see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Koebe_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following might work: Let $h : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}\backslash [0,\infty)$ be defined by $z \mapsto z^2$. This map is indeed biholomorphic, as we are considering only $\mathbb{H}$ as our domain. Then, define $f : \mathbb{C}\backslash[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty)$ by $z \mapsto z+1$. This is a biholomorphism. Then, let $F : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty)$ be defined by $F := f \circ h \circ g$. This should be your desired biholomorphic map.

Comment: The function $re^{i\theta} \mapsto re^{i(2\theta)}$ is not holomorphic (indeed it is the same as the map $z\mapsto z^2/|z|$). But the function $re^{i\theta} \mapsto r^2e^{i(2\theta)}$ is holomorphic (this is simply the map $z\mapsto z^2$) and should allow your argument to go through.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for pointing that out, I completely missed that.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the geometric intuition: We want to deform $\mathbb H$ into a slit plane. $h$ "fans out" the half plane to obtain such a slit plane, which just needs to be shifted around by $f$.